# How to tame a Star printer TSP743U

Tags: java, linux, windows, printing

We are developing using Java in different operating systems (Linux, Windows XP and Windows 8) and different machines and printers.

Part of the application consist in printing receipts. It is important for the application to generate the same form for all operating systems, machines and printers as a scanner is part of the application must be able to read the bar code generated.

Up to now we have not had any problem at all except when using a printer Star model STP743U, a machine IBM 4840 and Linux Mint or Windows xp, all other combinations work as they should.

The problem:

a.- printer STP743U, IBM 4840 and Windows Xp any receipt is printer after a blank page is printed (with another driver left margin takes almost half page width)

b.-   printer STP743U, IBM 4840 and LinuxMint : no left margin is printed

As I've said using printer STP743U, IBM 4840 with Windows 8 normal receipt are generated or, as other example, printer STP, Olivetti 206 with Linux Mint normal receipts are generated.

We have tried changing different drivers for the printer, reinstalling operating systems, using different machines (but always IBM 4840) with no progress.

Comment: This is more than likely not a code issue. This is probably the wrong site for this question.

Comment: Have you tried using an older version of Java?